# How to compute $x$ and $y$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, cryptography

How can one find in an efficient way $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ with max$\{|x|,|y|\} > 0$ as small as possible such that $\mid \pi x + e y \mid < 10^{-4}$ ?

I have reduced the following lattice basis:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 10^4\pi & 10^4e \end{pmatrix}

but is this the right one? And how can I use the reduced basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for $|1 -\frac yx\frac e\pi| \lt \frac 1{\pi x} 10^{-4}$.  Look at the continued fraction or Farey sequence converging to $\frac e\pi$.  Following the Farey sequence (start with $\frac 01$ and $\frac 11$, add numerators and denominators, replace one endpoint with the new fraction.  Using [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15548%2aexp%281%29-13453%2api), $\mid 13453 \pi - 15548 e \mid$ is just under $10^{-4}$

Comment: That is indeed one of the convergents. A larger one is 366031555/423032679.

Comment: @Charles:  I replaced the number with what I suspect is two more along the chain, using the Farey sequence.  It now fits, just barely.

Comment: Ah I see :-) Thank you very much!